# InputBox using VisualBasic.DLL requires DialogResult

Tags: c#, .net, inputbox

I'm using an InputBox from the Visual Basic Library and I need to determine which button has been selected by the end user. With the InputBox you can only grab the Entered Value by the user, I also need to detect if they hit Ok or Cancel.

Has anyone tried doing this before?

I know I could create a new form and do it that way, but wondering there's a workaround for this??

```
string answer =  Interaction.InputBox("Question","Title","");
```

I can determine if the user has input anything by the answer.length, but I need to know whether they hit "Cancel" or 
"Ok" after typing something as I need to abort on "Cancel".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, except for [checking the string length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox.aspx).

> If the user clicks Cancel, a zero-length string is returned.

So if you want to be able to distinguish between a click of the cancel button and the fact the user just entered an empty string, you're out of luck.

But there are plenty of custom implementations out there, [like this one on codeplex](http://inputbox.codeplex.com/), which will return a [`DialogResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx).

Comment: Here lies the problem i think, as if the user doesnt enter any info, i need to advise them that they cant proceed without entering a value. So if they hit ok, with no value, i cant distinguish between that and teh cancel button being pressed. If that makes sense?

Comment: @Derek Yes, that's the problem with `Interaction.InputBox`. Better use [this one](http://inputbox.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I have decided to make my own control, rather than using the one from codeplex one. Thanks for the help on this.